# What codecs does the 2.3-Gingerbread Internet calling (SIP) use?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, voip, sip

I am looking at the internet calling options in 2.3-Gingerbread. Does anyone know what codecs this dialer uses? 
Can the codecs be configured?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From a packet capture, the codecs are:

- GSM-EFR 8Khz
- AMR 8Khz
- GSM 8Khz
- G.711/PCMU 8Khz
- G.711/PCMA 8Khz

Here's the tidbit from the RTP packet capture:

```
m=audio 22728 RTP/AVP 96 97 3 0 8 127
a=rtpmap:96 GSM-EFR/8000
a=rtpmap:97 AMR/8000
a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:127 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:127 0-15
```

I couldn't find a way to configure the codecs either.

Comment: Awesome. I never thought of using packet capture.

Comment: This is also true for Android 5.0 Lollipop - supported by my own testing and [android.net.rtp.AudioCodec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/rtp/AudioCodec.html) documentation.